# How should i handle thousands of beacon?

Tags: cordova, ibeacon, beacon

i'm going to develop an app(with beacon integration) for a mall which has huge number of retail shops and with multiple floors. Take an example it has thousands of retail shops and each shop has it's own beacon/UUID beacon installed.

My questions are:
 1. How do i actually handle all the UUID? Should I store them in DB?
 2. How do i detect all the beacon's UUID on first floor only when
    customer reached the floor?
 3. We should not load all the thousands UUID at the same time right? How do we scan the UUID dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Designing a beacon identifier scheme is as much of an art as a science.  Doing it properly is heavily dependent on your specific use cases, particularly when you want to wake up the app in the background.  A few thoughts:

1. **You can only monitor for 20 ProximityUUIDs** at a time (using the limit of 20 `CLBeaconRegions`), so keep your number of ProximityUUIDs low.  **If possible, use only a single ProximityUUID for all beacons.**  Because of the low number needed, there is no reason to store them in a database.
2. It would be possible to use a single ProximityUUID and monitor and range for all beacons under this ProximityUUID.  Because there are 65536 possible major values and 65536 possible minor values, that means **you can have 4294967296 beacons with a single ProximityUUID.**  In theory, all will be visible to the app at the same time, but only when within the ~40 meter range of Bluetooth LE.  In practice, you will probably see a few dozen beacons from any location.
3. It is important to understand that each time a different `CLBeaconRegion` is detected or stops being detected, your app can get a background trigger.  **This is important if you want to have your app wake up to send notifications to the user as the mobile device moves round the mall.**  If your use case requires this, you will need to design an identifier scheme so you have a number of non-adjacent `CLBeaconRegion` definitions with different ProximityUUID/major combinations, so they will be triggered as you move around the mall.

Comment: Thanks David, very details answer. I will try it out :)